# Deploying Java project in Weblogic server

Tags: deployment

I have created a Java project. Which has a JMS Listener onMessage. How to deploy this java project in the weblogic server? There is another webproject in the weblogic server which will place an object in the Queue, that object needs to be consumed by my Java project. I need this Java project to be deployed independently. Please help.

Thanks,
Arvinth